# auto update a table from the databse without refreshing a page

Tags: php, html, ajax

i am new to php and ajax..

the problem i am facing is -

i am displaying a table in a jsp page.. and i want to auto update the table without

refreshing the page at every 10 sec.

i am retrieving the values for the database from a php page..

here is the code for data.jsp

```
   <html>
    <script type="text/javascript">

     function Ajax() 
    {
      var
            $http,
            $self = arguments.callee;

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            $http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            try {
                $http = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
            } catch(e) {
                $http = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
            }
        }

        if ($http) {
            $http.onreadystatechange = function()
            {
                if (/4|^complete$/.test($http.readyState)) {
                    document.getElementById('ReloadThis').innerHTML =             $http.responseText;
                    setTimeout(function(){$self();}, 10000);
                }
            };
            $http.open('GET', 'getuser.jsp', true);
            $http.send(null);
         }
    }
   function myFunction()
            {
        setTimeout(function() {ajax();}, 10000);
            }
    </script>
        </head>

       <body>

        <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
           <div   id="ReloadThis" > the table is to be shown here </div>
            </body>
          </html>
```

i wz doing the getuser part in php..but since tomcat doesnt supprt php.. so i converted my code to jsp.. and here is my code

and code for getuser.jsp

```
          <%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
         <%@page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement"%>
       <%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
             <%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>

           <%

                    String cond="SELECT * FROM invertor ";
                    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
                    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:xe");
                    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(cond);

                    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

                    if (rs.next()) 
                     {
                     dc_volt = rs.getString(1).trim();
                     dc_amp = rs.getString(2).trim();
                     ac_volt = rs.getString(3).trim();

                     ac_amp = rs.getString(4).trim();

                     }
                    else
                    {

                    }

                 %>
```

and the error i am getting is java.lang.arrayindexoutofboundsexception:2

after triggering the "try": button from my data.jsp page.. no databse table is showing...

Comment: What is the problem you have been facing?

Comment: You are declaring `$q=$_GET["q"];` but not using that, do you want to use that in searching in database and returning the value?

Comment: i edited my php.. check it.. and the problem is i am not getting any updated result..

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like this -

```
<script>
if ($http) {

     /*make the call*/
     $http.open('GET', 'getuser.php', true);               

     /* check for state change */
     $http.onreadystatechange = function()
            {
                if (/4|^complete$/.test($http.readyState)) {
                    document.getElementById('ReloadThis').innerHTML =             $http.responseText;
                    setTimeout(function(){$self();}, 10000);
                }
            };

     /*Because this is a GET request, the send values can be null*/       
     $http.send(null);
}
</script>
```